# Can't find the unity dash icon

Tags: unity, 18.04, icons, unity-dash, shortcuts

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and can't find the dash icon ...

[Here is a picture of the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBaPP.jpg)
It didn't exist in the first place when i installed Ubuntu, I looked in Tweaks but found nothing!

Comment: are you using gdm3 or Unity/ LightDM as Display Manager?

Comment: I checked with (cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager) I got gdm3

Comment: then below answer is rite. 9 dots or 3x3 grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 Has switched over to GNOME. The dash button has been replaced with "Show Applications" Button, 3x3 grid of dots, in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: Is there a way i can bring it back?

Comment: You should install unity/LightDM. You can simply Google it.. It gives very simple method. Can be done in less than 5minutes.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Unity back you can so this...
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
If I remember correctly while doing the download it will ask you in the terminal if you want to use LightDM.  Just select LightDM when asked if you want to have the Unity login screen too.  After everything is complete restart your computer and make sure everything is okay.  I did it and love it.  No issues when I did it on two different systems.